# How to get unicode string with WebClient DownloadData?

Tags: c#, string, unicode, webclient

Sorry for my bad English.

I am trying to get a string data with this code:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
byte[] buffer = wc.DownloadData("http://......);
string xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
```

the string has Unicode data. when I get this with my browser like firefox every things are ok.

But in my code the string is broken and xml file is useless. Some characters changed to their

decimal value and when reading xml file they are only characters that we can read. and others

changed  to strange signs.

Do you know how can I do?

Comment: broken how? what do you get and what did you expect to get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your data into a stream:

```
var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
```

And load it with the Load method:

```
doc.Load(stream);
```

This will try to detect the correct encoding.

Or maybe `WebClient.DownloadString` will work as well.

Comment: Thank you very much. DownloadString Worked.